# Ryzen AMD x86_64 increment for 64 bits on memory runs 8 times faster than 8,16 or 32 bit increment

Tags: c++, x86-64, atomic, amd-processor

I wanted to benchmark the atomic instructions compared to the non atomic, so I wrote the code that follows bellow. Besides benchmarking locked accesses I noticed a different aspect too that seems to me VERY VERY STRANGE and I would like to understand why !!!
It seems the processor does something WRONG !!! It could be that I am making any kind of simple error but I don't thing so !!!

The results showed that the time needed to increase a memory location non atomically (first column) was the same for the size 8,16,32 but not for 64 bits. Increasing memory contents of 64bits seems to be 8 times faster than other cases ( compare 4015744 to 541994 ) I did the benchmark on an AMD RYZEN processor.

```
 R[0]= 4015626 R[1]= 8891591 ratio:2.21425 // 8 bits 
 R[2]= 4014659 R[3]= 8885804 ratio:2.21334 // 16 bits
 R[4]= 4015744 R[5]= 8869814 ratio:2.20876 // 32 bits
 R[6]=  541994 R[7]= 8865181 ratio:16.3566 // 64 bits
```

On the other side increasing the memory contents of 8,16,32,64 sized memory (with a lock) is the same for all dimensions as it should be.

Doing an objdump I saw that:

The code compiled for 64bit memory contents increase is:

```
3550:   48 8b 44 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
3555:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
3559:   48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
```

The code compiled for 8bit memory contents increase is:

```
5470:   0f b6 44 24 0f          movzbl 0xf(%rsp),%eax
5475:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
5478:   88 44 24 0f             mov    %al,0xf(%rsp)
```

The full C++ CODE IS BELLOW (also https://godbolt.org/z/MYbs7nfdo attention on different processors behaves differently)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#define times0x80(x) {\
    x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x \
    x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x \
    x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x \
    x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x x x x \
}

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;

long R[8];
const size_t n=0x10000;

#define bbb(isAtomic,x,int_size,code)\
    [](){\
        conditional_t< isAtomic,volatile atomic<int##int_size##_t>,volatile int##int_size##_t > a;\
        auto t1=high_resolution_clock::now();\
            for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++) times0x80(code)\
        auto t2=high_resolution_clock::now();\
        auto c=duration_cast<microseconds>(t2-t1);\
        R[x]=c.count();\
    }\

#define jj(x) t##x.join();
#define pp(x) cout<<right<<" R["<<x<<"]="<<R[x]<<" R["<<x+1<<"]="<<R[x+1]<<" ratio:"<<double(R[x+1])/double(R[x])<<endl;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    for(int i=0x4;i--!=0;){
        {   
#define ms 10000
            bbb(0,0, 8,a+=1;)();cout<<"0 done"<<endl;
            bbb(1,1, 8,a+=1;)();cout<<"1 done"<<endl;
            bbb(0,2,16,a+=1;)();cout<<"2 done"<<endl; 
            bbb(1,3,16,a+=1;)();cout<<"3 done"<<endl; 
            bbb(0,4,32,a+=1;)();cout<<"4 done"<<endl; 
            bbb(1,5,32,a+=1;)();cout<<"5 done"<<endl; 
            bbb(0,6,64,a+=1;)();cout<<"6 done"<<endl; 
            bbb(1,7,64,a+=1;)();cout<<"7 done"<<endl; 

            //jj(0) jj(1) jj(2) jj(3) jj(4) jj(5) jj(6) jj(7)
            pp(0) pp(2) pp(4) pp(6)

            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilation command (compiler and options) please ?

Comment: It could be that 64 bits don't run into false sharing coincidentally. Who knows; there isn't enough information to reproduce this reliably.

Comment: @RichardCritten g++ -O3  -l pthread main.cpp

Comment: @user17732522 The volatile is to avoid the compiler to optimize converting 100 reads into a single one

Comment: is times0x100 supposed to have 128 x's?

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to trick a compiler into keeping successive increments intact. Anyway, here's a fun detail that doesn't seem to explain this either, but: Zen2 and 4 have memory renaming, but only for 32-bit and 64-bit operands. That doesn't explain why 32-bit isn't faster.

Comment: @user17732522 the lock happens when the subject of the increase is a variable that is atomic. In that case the compiler prepends a LOCK to the addition instruction.

Comment: @qwr yes times0x100 should repeat the subject 256 times, ( yes you got it it does it only 128 times ... )

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Ah ok, I see what you meant now. You don't need to worry about the `volatile` on the `atomic`. Compilers currently do not optimize atomics this way.

Comment: GCC produces the shown output, but Clang uses `inc` directly on memory instead of `mov`/`add`/`mov`. I suppose there is a difference in how GCC and Clang interpret/implement the behavior of `volatile` access. GCC might consider it necessary that load and store are in separate instructions. Otherwise I don't see why it would use that sequence.

Comment: @user17732522 Ok! but the results are similar or different ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I didn't test it.

Comment: @harold 8 times faster is EXTREME !!! I cannot understand how can it be!

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis *if* this is an effect due to memory renaming, which I don't know for sure, then that's about right: that effectively changes the load/add/store sequence (with a dependency through memory, very bad) into incrementing a register (memory not in the critical path)

Comment: @harold The only explanation I have is that no load and stores are done, may be 8 sequences of instructions are unified in only one ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis well not quite, note that load and store both have a latency of 4 (source: instruction tables from [Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/)) without memory renaming, and without renaming they *are* in the critical path, so the latencies add up. With renaming, I'm not entirely sure which loads and stores still happen, more than zero for sure - but they wouldn't be on the critical path, the `add` would depend on the previous `add` directly.

Comment: I would expect extra time when using integer sizes small than the processor word size.  The processor fetches 64 bits then has to perform extra work to reduce the 64 bits to the desired size, then increment.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's the role of the `movzbl` (move with zero extension) here, it does not by itself cost extra time compared to a regular `mov` on Ryzen. It has to be a more complex issue than that.

Comment: I checked on my laptop that has an Intel processor, and all times are equal ( the unlocked is 4 times faster than the locked ).

Comment: 8-core AMD Vishera - all tests equal. NOTE `i` is shadowed between loop and loop in macro.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You mean that both atomic and non atomic are the same indifferent of sizes ?

Comment: I confirm that the increment DOES HAPPEN ( all 8 routines do increment correctly the variable a).

Comment: What CPU model number?  "Ryzen" includes Zen 1 through Zen 4, and as Harold pointed out, there are effects like Zen 2 and Zen 4 that make store-forwarding latency effectively zero, so yeah, I'd expect about 6x to 8x faster than non-atomic `volatile int8_t`, since the loop bottleneck is just 1-cycle `add` latency instead of store/reload latency + `add` latency.  (But as Harold said, that should work for int32_t as well as int64_t.)  You're comparing `lock inc` vs. mov/add/mov for the same size here, and yeah a 2.2x ratio is similar to Intel `lock inc [mem]` vs. `inc [mem]`. https://uops.info/

Comment: And BTW, this source code is *painful* to read.  A rats nest of macros and lambdas, leaving just a meaningless block of numbers.  `times[0] = bbb(0, int8_t);` would be a lot more readable, since then it would be obvious how the `8` was being used, and a meaningful name for the result array.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will agree the code is painful to read !!! May be I should have uploaded an expanded copy. My CPU is "AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G with Radeon Graphics".